# Distribution of text by word count in Spark Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark, sorry if this question seem to easy for you. I'm trying to come up with the Spark-like solution, but can't figure out the way to do it.

My DataSet looks like following:

```
+----------------------+
|input                 |
+----------------------+
|debt ceiling          |
|declaration of tax    |
|decryption            |
|sweats                |
|ladder                |
|definite integral     |
```

I need to calculate distribution of Rows by length, e.g:

**1st option:**

- 500 rows contain 1 and more words
- 120 rows contain 2 and more words
- 70 rows contain 2 and more words

**2nd option:**

- 300 rows contain 1 word
- 250 rows contain 2 words
- 220 rows contain 3 words
- 270 rows contain 4 and more words

**Is there a possible solution using Java Spark functions?**
All I can think of, is writing some kind of UDF, that would have a broadcasted counter, but I'm likely missing something, since there should be a better way to do this in spark.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. This has a makings of a good question. Can you incdue some of the code you have tried so far, and explain where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Here is a solution in Scala you can easily adapt to Java.

```
val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  "debt ceiling", "declaration of tax", "decryption", "sweats"
)).toDF("input")

df.select(size(split('input, "\\s+")).as("words"))
  .groupBy('words)
  .count
  .orderBy('words)
  .show
```

This produces

```
+-----+-----+
|words|count|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    2|
|    2|    1|
|    3|    1|
+-----+-----+
```